# for loop doesn't work - what do I do wrong?

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

I am new to JavaScript. I would appreciate if you could help me with the code: thanks!

I'm trying to hide the answers to 10 questions and show them when clicked on the right button!
It only shows the last answer when i klick any button!

```
var ya = document.getElementsByClassName("A");
$(ya).hide();

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("idcheck");
  var z = x[i].id;

  console.log(x[i]);

  $(x[i]).click(function() {
    var y = document.getElementsByClassName(z);
    $(y).show();
  });
}
```

This is the html:

```
<p>
  <button id="B<?php echo $drow['id'];?>" class="btn btn-primary idcheck" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseExample" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
    Lösung der Aufgabe!
  </button>
</p>
    <td><b class="text-success A B<?php echo $drow['id'];?>"><?php echo $brow['answertext'];?></b></td>
    </tr>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Step 1: do your debugging properly before asking. That sounds mean, but it helps you help yourself now and in the future. Actually read through your code, saying what each line does out loud. And when you pass over them: what does `var z = ... ` do? And then what does `document.getElementsByClassName(z);` do? There is a lot that should be improved here, but you should be able to spot the actual problem here yourself. For the rest of the inefficiencies and code quirks, you should probably ask for code review over on the code review stackexchange.

Comment: The first advise I'd give you as a new developer is that you should give to your variables some name that helps you to recognize what represent them. X, Y and Z are not good names, even if you are doing a test.

Comment: why are you not just using jQuery to select the elements?

Comment: Thank you guys, I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code you've use jQuery as well as bootstrap specific elements. So I'm assuming that you'r page has jQuery.

Please have a look at the following snippet

NOTE: I've cleaned up your HTML structure and removed unnecessary bootstrap specific classes

```js
$('.idcheck') // We select all elements with the given class
  .on('click', function() { // We attach a function for the 'click' event
    var currID = $(this).attr('id').replace(/^B/i, ''); // We get teh ID fo the clicked buttona and remove 'B' from the start of it to it it's index

    $('.B' + currID).show(); // We then use the index and generate a class selector to target the <td> tag to show it

  })
```

```css
.A {
  display: none; // Hide the element initially
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <button id="B1" class="btn btn-primary idcheck" type="button">
        Button for ID 1
      </button>
    </td>
    <td><b class="text-success A B1">Content for ID 1</b></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <button id="B2" class="btn btn-primary idcheck" type="button">
        Button for ID 2
      </button>
    </td>
    <td><b class="text-success A B2">Content for ID 2</b></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is way more complicated than it needs to be. If you use jQuery, just stick with jQuery.

```
$(".A").hide();  
$(".idcheck").on("click", function() {
  var id = this.id;
  $("." + id).show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

1) If you use jquery, use jquery!
2) have a look at *scoping in js*

```
$(".A").hide();

$(".idcheck").each(function(){
  $(this).click(function() {
    $("."+$(this).id).show();
  });
});
```

Comment: Same as `$(".idcheck").on("click,function() {
    $("."+$(this).id).show();
});`